# Reports in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mysql, report, laravel-5

I want to generate a report from a table, like

```
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+------------+----------------+
| Field       | Type             | Null | Key | Default    | Extra          |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+------------+----------------+
| productID   | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL       | auto_increment |
| productCode | char(3)          | NO   |     |            |                |
| name        | varchar(30)      | NO   |     |            |                |
| quantity    | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | 0          |                |
| price       | decimal(7,2)     | NO   |     | 99999.99   |                |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+------------+----------------+
```

and show with some graphic the the top sellers. I'm lost in this subject. 
Is there a package that make this reports? 
Thanks for the info in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a package to generate the reports. Reports are all about getting data from DB, analyze and send output to the client/browser. What I would suggest is that get the data from DB and send to the client as JSON. In client side, you can use graph plotting packages like [Highchart](http://www.highcharts.com), [D3JS](https://d3js.org) etc to plot the graph.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. :)